# Deriving headroom for the 34063

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I've hit a design dead-end because, after running the numbers for an [SP34063A](https://assets.maxlinear.com/web/documents/sipex/datasheets/sp34063a_ds_r211_020614.pdf)-driven SMPS, it seems it doesn't have enough headroom. This was not described directly in either the [OnSemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN920-D.PDF) or [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva252b/slva252b.pdf) application notes I worked through, but instead a consequence of timing constraints.

I had intended to make a standard buck configuration with

- Vin = 12V
- Vout = 10V
- Vf ~= 500 mV for a [DSS12UTR](http://www.smc-diodes.com/propdf/DSS12U%20THRU%20DSS125U%20N1873%20REV.A.pdf) at 1A peak
- Vsat ~ 1.0 < 1.3V in Darlington mode
- 5.2 < timing charge ratio ~ 6.5 < 7.5

The intended topology:

[image: buck]

Based on the application note's description of

[image: tontoff]

I have

$$
\frac {t_{on}} {t_{off}} > 
\frac {V_o + V_f} {V_i - V_{sat (\min)} - V_o }
$$

$$
\frac {t_{on}} {t_{off}} >  10
$$

On the other end, the application note says

[image: ratio]

which just evaluates to

$$
\frac {t_{on}} {t_{off}} < 
\frac {I_{charge}} {I_{discharge}} (\min)
$$

$$
\frac {t_{on}} {t_{off}} < 5.2
$$

For the original design figures, these inequalities are disjoint so it's non-implementable.

This suggests that I either need to decrease Vo below 9.187 V, or increase Vi above 12.969 V, neither of which I can do in circuit; so I'd have to go with a different SMPS, maybe SEPIC but more likely LDO at this point.

Is this analysis correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This suggests that I either need to decrease Vo below 9.187 V, or
> increase Vi above 12.969 V, neither of which I can do in circuit; so
> I'd have to go with a different SMPS, maybe SEPIC but more likely LDO
> at this point.
>
> Is this analysis correct?

It looks about right to me (or at least the conclusion is correct).

In Emitter Follower configuration the typical saturation voltage is ~1.4 V, leaving only ~0.6 V of theoretical headroom when going from 12 V to 10 V. But that would require an on/off ratio of >17:1, which this device cannot do.

More modern switching regulator ICs use FETs for lower voltage drop, and some have synchronous rectification which eliminates flyback diode voltage drop. Many of these can work with an input-output differential of less than 1 V.

If your average operating current is low and the input voltage doesn't go much above 12 V then an LDO regulator might be a good alternative. It will get a little hotter and may need a heat sink, but efficiency should still be acceptable for most purposes, and it could have 'quieter' output (less ripple and noise).

SEPIC is required if the input-output voltage differential may dip below the dropout voltage of a buck or linear regulator.

Comment: _More modern switching regulator ICs use FETs for lower voltage drop_ - Like the  [AP3211](http://fweb.wallawalla.edu/~frohro/ClassHandouts/Intro_to_Cad/2018/AP3211.pdf) ? I don't see how to do the same headroom analysis but maybe it shouldn't be as important in this case.

Comment: That IC has an NMOSFET which requires boosted Gate voltage. This is derived from the SW output so maximum duty cycle is limited to 90%. Dropout voltage and behavior isn't specified so you would have to test it. A better option might be the XL4013, which has 100% max duty cycle and 0.3V dropout. http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL4013%20datasheet-English.pdf

Comment: That looks a little tricky to source. The [AP63356Q](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP63356Q_AP63357Q.pdf) looks promising and has an explicit low dropout mode.

Comment: AP63356Q looks good (if you don't mind the dfn package). It has an 'LDO' mode that keeps the bootstrap capacitor charged even with '100%' PWM.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this analysis correct?

No. It is not my purpose in this answer to promote the use of the 34063. However, I am pained by the truly awful documentation provided by the various manufacturers of this chip, which documentation leads to confusion which has found its way into your analysis. I want to do a small bit to clear up some of this confusion.

The largest offender in this case is the documentation's conflation of the time in which the diode is conducting (which I will call \$t_{D(on)}\$) with the time that the switching transistor is off. The documentation uses the term \$t_{off}\$ to sometimes mean what I call \$t_{D(on)}\$, and sometimes uses it to mean the time that the switching transistor is off. The two **are** in fact the same **if** the converter is operating in Continuous Conduction Mode (CCM), but are **NOT** equal if the converter is operating in Discontinuous Conduction Mode (DCM).

The MC34063 has an internal clock, which is controlled in the first instance by a timing capacitor. It has a rise time and a fall time. The rise time may be cut short if the current sense input detects that the current through the switch is at, or above, a value programmed by a sense resistor. Generally, this occurs during startup of the converter, but typically does not occur during the cyclic steady state of the converter unless the load attempts to draw too much current.

A buck converter based on the MC34063 has an inductor, whose current **also** rises and falls. But although the 34063's clock and the converter's inductor both have rising and falling phases, it is important to note that these two processes are not completely in synch. The rising of the inductor current may start **after** the rising of the clock, if the feedback voltage was above a threshold at the start of a cycle. But more importantly, the falling of the inductor current may stop **before** the falling of the clock stops. The inductor current may reach zero before the end of a clock cycle, and in that case, we say that the converter is operating in DCM. The MC34063 neither knows, nor cares if or when the inductor current ceases.

In it's normal operating regime, the rising phase of the clock is between 5.2 and 7.5 times longer than the falling phase. When the documentation says that the operating frequency of a converter is given by

$$\frac{1}{f} = t_{on}+t_{off}$$

(as for example in [TI's datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) page 11) they are using \$t_{on}\$ to mean the clock's rising time, and \$t_{off}\$ to mean the clocks falling time. But when [Onsemi's Application Note AN920D](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN920-D.PDF) on page 7 gives the formula

$$\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}} = \frac{V_{out}+V_F}{V_{in(min)}-V_{sat}-V_{out}}$$

they are using \$t_{on}\$ to mean what I would call \$t_{Q(on)}\$ (the time the switching transistor is on) and \$t_{off}\$ to mean what I would call \$t_{D(on)}\$ the time the diode is conducting. They actually say so explicitly.

> Determine the ratio of switch conduction \$t_{on}\$ versus diode conduction \$t_{off}\$ time.
>
> $$\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}} = \frac{V_{out}+V_F}{V_{in(min)}-V_{sat}-V_{out}}$$

But then they go on to confuse matters by stating that

> The cycle time of the LC (sic!?) network is equal to \$t_{on(max)} + t_{off}\$.

We might be tempted to believe that there is some requirement that a converter based on the MC34063 must operate in CCM. But we turn to TI's [application note slva252b](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva252b/slva252b.pdf) page 6. In TI's app note we find the same formula as above without the "min" as

$$\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}} = \frac{V_{out}+V_F}{V_{in}-V_{sat}-V_{out}}$$

But here is the kicker. The app note describes in the same paragraph that

> **the system is operating in the discontinuous mode.**

Examples of equivocation in the use of the term \$t_{off}\$ abound in the documentation. So, when we read in Onsemi's application note page 7

> Note that the ratio of \$t_{on}/(t_{on} + _{toff})\$ does not exceed the maximum of 6/7 or 0.857. This maximum is defined by the 6:1 ratio of charge−to−discharge current of timing capacitor \$C_T\$

we are bound to wonder what is meant by the terms, and whether this means that there is a maximum ratio between \$t_{Q(on)}\$ and \$t_{D(on)}\$? But there cannot be. The 34063 neither knows, nor cares, if and/or when the catch diode stops conducting. The "6:1" ratio refers to the clock and does not limit \$t_{Q(on)}/t_{D(on)}\$. If we operate in DCM, \$t_{D(on)}\$ can be made much shorter than the clock falling phase.

To show this, I have designed the following circuit.

[image]

Here are the waveforms for the voltage across the timing capacitor \$C_T\$ and the current through L1.

[image]

Inspection shows that the current through L1 falls to it's minimum of 0 mA, faster than the clock voltage falls to it's minimum of about 0.5V. The current through L1 then stays at 0 for a short bit before both it, and the voltage at \$C_T\$ begin to climb again. This period where the current through L1 is 0 is the defining characteristic of DCM.

The circuit does indeed give an output of approimately 10 V, with an input of 12 V, as designed.

[image]

It can be seen that the raw output has a rather significant ripple of about 80 mV, peak-to-valley. This is why I added a second LC section. After the second LC section, the filtered output has a ripple of only about 3.3 mV.

If ripple was a problem, why did I use the surprisingly low frequency I did? Why didn't I use a higher frequency? Why didn't I use a larger inductor?

To explain the low frequency chosen, we must first realize that the 34063 is, um, *slow*. When the current through the sense resistor reaches a threshold defined by \$R_{sense}\$, the timing capacitor is charged to its upper threshold, and the switching transistor is turned off. According to a note in the TI datasheet, page 5

> it may take up to 2 μs for the switch to come out of saturation.

While we are operating the switching transistor in Darlington mode, there will still be a delay between when the threshold current is reached and the switching transistor is off. Since it could be any value up to 2 \$\mu\text{s}\$, we must conservatively plan for 2 \$\mu\text{s}\$. During that time, the current will continue to rise. However, we must avoid the absolute maximum switching current of 1.5 A.

The peak current is shown at startup
[image]

The formula I used for finding the peak current is

$$I_{max} = I_{th} + \frac{V_{in} \times t_{prop}}{L}$$

where \$t_{prop}\$ is the propagation delay to turn off the switching transistor.

rearranging gives

$$L = \frac{V_{in} \times t_{prop}}{I_{max}-I_{th}}$$

I then did the calculation

$$L = \frac{12\times 2\mu s}{1.5-1.0}  = 48 \mu\text{H}$$

So, an inductor of 68 \$\mu\$H is chosen. But recall, that we want the converter to operate in DCM, so that we can get the 10 V output, which is requires a high ratio of inductor current rise, to inductor current fall. But to get DCM with an inductor of that size requires either low frequency, or low current, or both. These, in turn, led to high voltage ripple in the raw output, prompting the second LC section to reduce that ripple.

Incidentally, the simulation was showing sub-harmonic oscillation, and adding C3 seemed to cure that. I did not use a formula, but simply increased the value until the sub-harmonic oscillations disappeared.

Comment: It's all very interesting. I wish manufacturers of this device just published an easy-to-reference minimum headroom, in addition to the clarity you've shown. I ended up using a 34063 for a simple case, and an AP63356 for a more design-constrained case; I'm quite happy with the performance of both so far.

Comment: Great answer. There should be more materials available discussing why the 34063 is a poor performer, and this illustrates well several of its issues -- not just practical (look at those huge inductors and capacitors!) but documentation as well.  This also illustrates the issue with appnotes, that are all too often poorly written. If one really needs everything the 34063 is otherwise capable of, I would suggest a nudge in the direction of NCV3063 and friends; it's still hysteretic, but at least it's faster, and claims actual peak current limiting, not the oscillator hack.